# Single page not working for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, single

I created a custom post type with the following code:

```
add_action('init', 'create_trans_career');

function create_trans_career() {
    //Arguments to create post type.
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Career', 'trans'),
            'singular_name' => __('Career', 'trans'),
            'add_new' => __('Add New', 'trans'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Career Item', 'trans'),
            'edit' => __('Edit', 'trans'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Career Item', 'trans'),
            'new_item' => __('New Career', 'trans'),
            'view' => __('View', 'trans'),
            'view_item' => __('View Career', 'trans'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Career', 'trans'),
            'not_found' => __('No Career item found', 'trans'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Career item found in Trash', 'trans'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory'). '/images/career-icon.png',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'career', 'with_front' => false),
    );

    //Register type and custom taxonomy for type.
    register_post_type( 'career' , $args );
}
```

I also created a single page (single-career.php):

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <hr />
            <?php the_content('Read More...'); ?>
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/career" title="<?php _e('Back to jobs listings', 'trans'); ?>" class="back-to-jobs"><?php _e('Back to jobs listings', 'trans'); ?></a>
            <?php endwhile;  ?>
```

..and a page template to list the posts:

```
$mypost = array( 'post_type' => 'career', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $pagedNum );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $mypost ); ?>
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
            <tr id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $location; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $close_date; ?></td>
                <td><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Details', 'trans'); ?>"><?php _e('&gt; Details', 'trans'); ?></a></td>
                <td class="apply-now"><a data-title="<?php the_title(); ?>" data-location="<?php echo $location; ?>" href="#apply_<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php _e('Apply Now', 'trans'); ?>" class="career-apply"><?php _e('Apply Now', 'trans'); ?></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile;  ?>
```

I created a page with jobs using the template above.. it's working I see all posts.. but when I open a single page I receive 404 error. Where is the problem?

Comment: What URL is it trying to reach when it 404s?

Comment: Did you refresh permalink settings?

Comment: career/test-job-title

Comment: How can I refresh and why is it necessary?

Comment: To refresh simply visit the permalinks page in settings. It will make sure all of your pretty permalinks (including /career/) are upto date.

Comment: One more question for this.. I created the page with XY slug. Is it possible to redirect /career to the career template url?

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your functions.php:

```
/* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'bt_flush_rewrite_rules' );

/* Flush your rewrite rules */
function bt_flush_rewrite_rules() {
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Then change your theme to a different theme and then set it back again to your custom theme.
This will flush the rewrite rule and making the custom post working properly.

Comment: followed your instructions but not working :(

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: You could just go to your permalink settings and press save to flush your rewrite rules. This is a very weird and unnecessary workaround.

Answer (score 0):

@welbyaudry solution works but the process is a bit lengthy. I want to make it simpler for others. Just place the below code in the functions.php of your active theme and refresh your page.

```
/* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'init', 'bt_flush_rewrite_rules' );

/* Flush your rewrite rules */
function bt_flush_rewrite_rules() {
     flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there are lots of different problems and potential solutions here, but after trying every other suggested solution, none of which worked, I found something that worked. Add:

flush_rewrite_rules();

after you call register_post_type.